# Feature selection by doing pairwise KS test between different features in a dataset

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, supervised-learning, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I am trying to build a supervised learning model (binary class) and I wanted to check whether the features belonging to the respective classes come from the same distribution or not. Because the ones that don't have any distributional differences are likely to be less predictive. To achieve that, I did a two sample KS test between pairs of features and found out which are significant. So if my dataset had 3 features ${V1,V2,V3}$ and two classes (1 and 2), then I performed $KS(V1class1, V1class2)$, $KS(V2class1,V2class2)$ and so on. Now I have three p values that can help me find out which features are really different. Is this the right way of doing this?

Comment: two variables could have the same distribution and yet be completely independent. and both be good predictors, or not... the distribution means nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KS does not do what you expect it to do. You’re looking for something like correlation or, more broadly, dependence, something like mutual information. Let’s look at an example.

$$A: 1,2,3,4$$
$$B: 2,3,1,4$$

These have the same distribution but are independent. (I picked $B$ at random.) With a larger sample size but the same idea, your KS test would call these redundant and drop one, although they are unrelated and provide unique information about the response variable

Let’s look at the reverse.

$$C: 1,2,3,4$$
$$D: 100,200,300,400$$

These are perfectly correlated; perhaps $C$ is measured in meters while $D$ is measured in centimeters. You would not want to include both features, as they are totally redundant. However, the distributions are certainly different, and with more observations but the same idea, your KS test would reject. You then would include both variables, even though they give identical information about the response variable.

Comment: So what test should I perform between the feature pairs to say that they are really different in some sense? Can you please name some? I am not so much interested in doing feature selection. I just wanted to find out whether they are different

Comment: Variance inflation factor is probably the first method people learn for this sort of issue, but there’s so much that goes into feature selection that it really warrants a separate question (which likely has been covered extensively on here and on datascience.stackexchange.com).

Comment: How about chi square test of independence between the features? That should tell us whether these are really independent, right?

Comment: The trouble with pairwise testing is that features can be independent while being conditionally dependent. The topic of feature selection is extensive and warrants its own question, though I expect there to be many discussions about the topic already on Cross Validated and Data Science.